# Order by date and time

Tags: mysql

I have two varchar fields which store the date and time in the following format:
date=2010-08-18; time=07:53:55;

What would be the right sql query to show me the events from the most recent to the oldest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from recommending that you use MySQL datetime fields rather than VARCHARs for any date or time values; what about something simple like adding an ORDER BY clause to your query:

```
ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, `TIME` DESC
```